# Open EditAppointmentDialog MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I currently have a viewmodel such that it has a grid full of appointments. I would like to double click and open up my CalendarView with the editappointmentdialog opened for the record that was selected. May I ask how would I do that in an MVVM style?

I searched the internet and found this `RadScheduleViewCommands.EditAppointment.Execute(appointment, this.scheduleView);` but I don't have access to the scheduleView object from the MVVM. May I ask how abouts I should do this?

I think I can achieve this if I relay it back to the view, but I'm trying to look for another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you can't open a view from a view model as it'll break the MVVM design pattern.

There are a couple of ways you can open a view from the view model without too much hassle:

- Implement a **Messenger** service to publish an event to the view, like [MVVMLight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/jj694937.aspx) does.
- Straight up add a `Click` event handler on your button and open the view in the code behind (It's still view code after all).

However my **preferred** method is to use an `ICommand`, or `RelayCommand`. I have written a [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mike-eason/MVVM_WindowCommands) which demonstrates how to achieve this.